# How to use scanf in a Swift environment

Tags: oop, interface, objective-c, user-interface, user-controls

I am practicing Objective C to get a better understanding of C and was using the newest Xcode, but using the terminal to write simple programs. In the the program below is can't seem to get the scanf function to work. Is there a different function that I can use to input data into the terminal to check the rest of syntax and coding?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, number, triangularNumber;

    NSLog (@"What triangular number do you want?");

    scanf ("%i", &number);

    triangularNumber = 0;

    for ( n = 1; n <= number; ++n )
        triangularNumber += n;

    NSLog (@"Triangular number %i is %i\n", number, triangularNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space in between the `scanf` and `()`. The `scanf` function should turn purple when done correctly. Just take out the space and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this (this is Swift, Objective C is the same):

```
let handle = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
let input = NSString(data: handle.availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```